# Threads and threadgroups in Metal

Tags: macos, gpu, metal

I have some questions around threads per threadgroups and number of threadgroups.

1. Since, we have `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` and `threadExecutionWidth`, the `length * width * height` of a threadgroup should be equal to `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup`. So, if I have `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup = 1024`, and `threadExecutionWidth = 32`, what difference does it make if I make a threadgroup of size `(1024 * 1 * 1)` or `32 * 32 * 1`? Is there any added benefit for the total GPU execution time? Or this is just for more effective management?
2. If I want to run threads more than `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` then I shall make multiple threadgroups. Is it safe to assume that `ThreadGroup1` will be executed before `ThreadGroup2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an authoritative source on Metal compute, and lots of details such as this are not documented, so take the following with a grain of salt:

1. Organizing the threadgroups into 1, 2, or 3 dimensions is mostly a convenience for you as the developer. If your problem is three-dimensional, use threadgroups with 3 dimensions. If your problem is one-dimensional, use threadgroups with 1 dimension. Metal doesn't really care one way or the other.
2. I don't think you can assume anything about the order in which the GPU threads from your threadgroups are scheduled.

For example, if you schedule 10 threadgroups that each compute an intermediate result (for example a sum), then you probably shouldn't depend on the 10th threadgroup to collect these results and combine them into one final result (the final sum). Instead, you'll have to launch a new compute kernel to do this.

(I'd be happy to be proven wrong about this, but I haven't read anywhere that Metal guarantees this sort of thing.)

Comment: Probably that is the reason why Metal does not have any prewritten kernels for sorting and prefix sums. With a restriction on number of threads in a threadgroup and no surety about which threadgroup is executed first, I think there is no way to write such programs without multiple invocations of compute kernel.

Comment: But isn't that true for all GPGPU languages?

Comment: I'm not sure. I see sorting and prefix sum APIs for CUDA, using thrust libraries. Are you saying thrust also invokes multiple kernels to sort data or compute prefix sum?

Comment: Prefix sum (or scan) can typically be done with a single threadgroup. Not sure how sorting is implemented in CUDA. But yes, splitting an operation into multiple stages that each have their own compute kernel, is a common approach. You can't communicate between different threadgroups -- I guess relying on a specific order in which they're performed is a type of communication.

Comment: Are you saying I can have stages for compute shaders like a rendering pipeline stage?

Comment: You can encode multiple GPU kernels in the same command buffer and then run the entire command buffer at once.

Comment: Is there a tutorial or documentation for this? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Create your command buffer. For each kernel you want to run, create a new compute command encoder for this the command buffer, encode the kernel. Once you've done this for all your kernels, commit the command buffer. The GPU will now run all your compute kernels one after the other, but all in the same job.

Comment: Important thing to note is that going for either a 1024 * 1 * 1 or 32 * 32 * 1 thread group can definitely matter! In the first case you're computing your line by line, in the second case in a square. Generally you will have more coherency in terms of what memory you want to access in the square option since every pixel "sees" the same object for example. You will then have the benefit of increased cache hits :)!

Comment: @JaapWijnen I don't really disagree but that's more an issue of how you divide up the work than how you set up a threadgroup. In the case of 1024x1x1 you can still do the work in 32x32 blocks inside the shader. Of course, it would make more sense to set it up as 32x32x1 if you're going to do that, for sure.